# How to pass recordid value from custom LWC component to Chatter Feed component in Experience Builder?

Tags: lightning-web-components, chatter, experience-cloud, chatter-feed

I am trying to configure Chatter Feed component on Partner Portal along side a custom LWC component which shows Lead's Detail.

It works fine if I select "My Feed" but I want record specific posts only and hence when I select feed type as "Group or Record", I need to pass recordId from my custom component on that page to Record Id field of Chatter feed settings. I have tried with @api to pass the recordId from custom component to Feed but it doesn't work.

[image]